# How does CurrentControlSet differ from ControlSet001 and ControlSet002?

Tags: windows, registry

In the Windows registry, how does `CurrentControlSet` differ from
`ControlSet001` and `ControlSet002`? Which should be set when installing for all
users?

We are trying to add an environment variable for all users. Is this correct?

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Envinronment
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, you only need to update the `CurrentControlSet` key...

`ControlSet001` and `ControlSet002` are alternating backups of
`CurrentControlSet`, you don't need to update them.

Edit: As K noted, `CurrentControlSet` is an alternating symbolic link to either
`ControlSet001` or `ControlSet002`. The other key is kept as a backup for the
Load Last Known Good Configuration boot option.

Edit 2: See Microsoft KB Article 100010: What are Control Sets? What is CurrentControlSet?
[Original page link broken](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010), see [archive.org backup page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217152952/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010) instead.

Comment: As the KB article points out, the current ControlSet number is set by the `Select` DWORD in `HKLM\System`

Comment: My mistake - `HKLM\System\Select` is a key, and in there is a `Current` DWORD that sets the current ControlSet.

Answer (score 15):

`CurrentControlSet` is technically not a "backup" as Gordon states.
It is a symbolic link to one of the `ControlSet`s on the computer. It always
points to the `ControlSet` that is currently loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Actual symbolic link match is in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Select\`.

Answer (score 2):

ControlSet001 may be the last control set you booted with, while ControlSet002 could be what is known as the last known good control set, or the control set that last successfully booted Windows

Answer (score 0):

The `CurrentControlSet` subkey is really a pointer to one of the `ControlSetXXX`
keys.

The most valuable and reliable control set is `CurrentControlSet`. If you need
to modify system settings in the Registry, `CurrentControlSet` is the best
subkey to choose because you know that it is the correct control set.