# Read monitor name like MultiMonitor tool does

Tags: delphi

I would like to know if there is a way in Delphi to read the **monitor name** as I see it in the **MultiMonitorTool** program:

[image]

At the moment, I have tried to read it via the following methods:

- `MonitorInfo.szDevice` (it returns `"\\.\DISPLAY1"`)
- `monitorname(Screen.Monitors[i].MonitorNum)` (it returns `"Generic-Non-PnP-Monitor"`)
- `Screen.Monitors[i].FriendlyName` (it returns `"Generic-Non-PnP-Monitor"`)

```pascal
procedure TMonitorOrientationDemoForm.RefreshMonitorsList;
var
  i: integer;
  li: TListItem;
  MonitorInfo: TMonitorInfoEx;
  LTmp: string;

  function ArrayToString(const a: array of Char): string;
  begin
    if Length(a) > 0 then
      Result := StrPas(PChar(@a[0]))
    else
      Result := '';
  end;

begin
  lvMonitors.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    lvMonitors.Items.Clear;
    for i := 0 to Screen.MonitorCount - 1 do
    begin
      li := lvMonitors.Items.Add;
      MonitorInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MonitorInfo);
      if not GetMonitorInfo(Screen.Monitors[i].Handle, @MonitorInfo) then
        continue;
      LTmp := ArrayToString(MonitorInfo.szDevice);
      //Screen.Monitors[i].FriendlyName -> returns the string "Generic-Non-PnP-Monitor"
      //MonitorInfo.szDevice -> returns the string "\\.\DISPLAY1"
      //monitorname(Screen.Monitors[i].MonitorNum) -> returns the string "Generic-Non-PnP-Monitor"
      LI.Caption := Screen.Monitors[i].FriendlyName;
      li.SubItems.Add(MonitorOrientationToString(Screen.Monitors[i].Orientation));
      if Screen.Monitors[i].SupportsRotation then
        li.SubItems.Add('Yes')
      else
        li.SubItems.Add('No');
    end;
  finally
    lvMonitors.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

function TMonitorOrientationDemoForm.monitorname(numberof: integer): string;
Var
  Cntr: Cardinal;
  Info: TDisplayDevice;
  AdapterName: PChar;
  OldPos, j, i: integer;
  a: tstringlist;
Begin
  a := tstringlist.create;
  Cntr := numberof;
  Info.cb := SizeOf(Info);
  While EnumDisplayDevices(Nil, Cntr, Info, 0) Do
  Begin
    AdapterName := StrAlloc(SizeOf(Info.DeviceName));
    StrCopy(AdapterName, Info.DeviceName);
    EnumDisplayDevices(AdapterName, 0, Info, 0);
    a.Add(Info.DeviceString);
    for i := 1 to a.count - 1 do
    begin
      a.Delete(i);
      Result := a.Strings[0];
      StrDispose(AdapterName);
      Inc(Cntr);
    End;
  End;
End;
```

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1234471/how-can-i-easily-get-the-manufacturer-and-model-of-my-monitor) has the answer you look for but not using Delphi.

Comment: With the wmic command I still get the same output, probably for this reason here: https://superuser.com/questions/1245250/why-is-my-monitor-showing-up-as-generic-non-pnp-monitor. So how is it possible that mooltimonitortool can read the model name of the monitor? Probably if I had manually installed the monitor drivers as suggested in the link, I would also have been able to obtain the desired result via delphi. I am able to read the model name even through a small test program written in C# using the WindowsDisplayAPI library

Comment: Unfortunately the program in which I need that piece of code has to be distributed to several users, and it would be very inconvenient to have to manually set the drivers for each monitor.

Comment: Why don't you look how the C# program find out the monitor name? The [source code of WindowsDisplayAPI](https://github.com/falahati/WindowsDisplayAPI/tree/master/WindowsDisplayAPI) is available.

Comment: What's `FriendlyName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach, which is based on [`EnumDisplayDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa) and has described in several previous Qs [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060584/get-the-name-of-a-monitor), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958683/how-do-i-get-the-actual-monitor-name-as-seen-in-the-resolution-dialog)], can be written like this in Delphi:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  dd, md: TDisplayDevice;
begin

  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListBox1.Clear;
    FillChar(dd, SizeOf(dd), 0);
    dd.cb := SizeOf(dd);
    FillChar(md, SizeOf(md), 0);
    md.cb := SizeOf(md);
    var i := 0;
    while EnumDisplayDevices(nil, i, dd, 0) do
    begin
      var j := 0;
      while EnumDisplayDevices(@dd.DeviceName[0], j, md, 0) do
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Add(md.DeviceString);
        Inc(j);
      end;
      Inc(i);
    end;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;
```

On my system, this correctly identifies my three Dell monitors but fails to identify my Samsung wall-mounted TV ("Generic PnP Monitor").

[image: Screenshot of a Delphi application showing my four displays in a list box: Dell U2211H (Digital), Allmän PnP-bildskärm, Dell UP2716D (DP), and Dell UP2716D (DP)]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I also tried this type of approach, but in my case all the monitors return "Generic PnP Monitor" as a name. This I think is caused by the drivers: https://superuser.com/questions/1245250/why-is-my-monitor-showing-up-as-generic-non-pnp-monitor

Comment: Have you also tried `DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo`?

Comment: I still can't get the model name

Answer (score 3):

This is quite new to me and either because I execute it on *Windows 7* or because I also have a TV instead of a monitor I also only get a generic "*PnP-Monitor (Standard)*" with the usual approach. But the code below gives me a helpful result:

```
program stackoverflow68064094;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const
  user32= 'user32.dll';
  QDC_ALL_PATHS=                                1;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET=          2;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME=    2;
  ERROR_SUCCESS=                                0;

type
  LUID= Int64;
  LONG= LongInt;  // Just anything 32bit
  BOOL= LongBool;

  // ENUMs, all starting with 1
  DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS=   Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY=    Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION=                   Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING=                    Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING=          Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE=             Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT=                Cardinal;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID=                Cardinal;

  PDISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER= ^DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER= packed record
    typ, size: Cardinal;
    adapterId: LUID;
    id: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME= packed record
    header: DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER;
    flags: DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME_FLAGS;
    outputTechnology: DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY;
    edidManufactureId, edidProductCodeId: Word;
    connectorInstance: Cardinal;
    monitorFriendlyDeviceName: Array[0.. 64- 1] of WideChar;
    monitorDevicePath: Array[0.. 128- 1] of WideChar;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO= packed record
    adapterId: LUID;
    id, modeInfoIdx, statusFlags: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL= packed record
    Numerator, Denominator: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO= packed record
    adapterId: LUID;
    id, modeInfoIdx: Cardinal;
    outputTechnology: DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY;
    rotation: DISPLAYCONFIG_ROTATION;
    scaling: DISPLAYCONFIG_SCALING;
    refreshRate: DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL;
    scanLineOrdering: DISPLAYCONFIG_SCANLINE_ORDERING;
    targetAvailable: BOOL;
    statusFlags: Cardinal;
  end;

  PDISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO= ^DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO= packed record
    sourceInfo: DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_SOURCE_INFO;
    targetInfo: DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_TARGET_INFO;
    flags: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION= packed record
    cx, cy: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO= packed record
    pixelRate: UInt64;
    hSyncFreq, vSyncFreq: DISPLAYCONFIG_RATIONAL;
    activeSize, totalSize: DISPLAYCONFIG_2DREGION;
    videoStandard: Cardinal;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE= packed record
    targetVideoSignalInfo: DISPLAYCONFIG_VIDEO_SIGNAL_INFO;
  end;

  POINTL= packed record  // Or TPOINT right away
    x, y: LONG;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE= packed record
    width, height: Cardinal;
    pixelFormat: DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT;
    position: POINTL;
  end;

  RECTL= packed record  // Or TRECT right away
    left, top, right, bottom: LONG;
  end;

  DISPLAYCONFIG_DESKTOP_IMAGE_INFO= packed record
    PathSourceSize: POINTL;
    DesktopImageRegion, DesktopImageClip: RECTL;
  end;

  PDISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO= ^DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO;
  DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO= packed record
    infoType: DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE;
    id: Cardinal;
    adapterId: LUID;
    case Byte of
    1: ( targetMode: DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_MODE );
    2: ( sourceMode: DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE );
    3: ( desktopImageInfo: DISPLAYCONFIG_DESKTOP_IMAGE_INFO );
  end;

  PDISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID= ^DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID;


function GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes( flags: Cardinal;
  numPathArrayElements, numModeInfoArrayElements: PCardinal ): LONG; stdcall; external user32;  // Vista

function QueryDisplayConfig( flags: Cardinal; numPathArrayElements: PCardinal;
  pathArray: PDISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO; numModeInfoArrayElements: PCardinal;
  modeInfoArray: PDISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO;
  currentTopologyId: PDISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID ): LONG; stdcall; external user32;  // Windows 7

function DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(
  requestPacket: PDISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER ): LONG; stdcall; external user32;  // Vista


// Actually using all this
procedure GetFriendlyMonitorNames();
var
  vName: DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME;
  iPath, iMode: Cardinal;
  aPath: Array of DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO;
  aMode: Array of DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes( QDC_ALL_PATHS, @iPath, @iMode )= ERROR_SUCCESS then exit;
  SetLength( aPath, iPath );  // For me: 104...
  SetLength( aMode, iMode );  // ...and 30

  if not QueryDisplayConfig
  ( QDC_ALL_PATHS
  , @iPath, @aPath[0]
  , @iMode, @aMode[0]
  , nil
  )= ERROR_SUCCESS then exit;

  for i:= 0 to Integer(iMode)- 1 do begin
    case aMode[i].infoType of
      DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET: begin
        vName.header.size:= SizeOf( DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME );
        vName.header.adapterId:= aMode[i].adapterId;
        vName.header.id:= aMode[i].id;
        vName.header.typ:= DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME;
        if( DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo( @vName ) )= ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
          Writeln( vName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName );  // For me: M237WD
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  GetFriendlyMonitorNames();
end.
```

On an older netbook the friendly name is empty (successfull function call, tho), while the generic `.DeviceString` approach gives me "*Digital-Flachbildschirm (1280x1024 60Hz)*", which is more helpful. I guess one has to consider at least both approaches.

**Edit:** including all definitions translated from C++, written by hand. Now it's a complete program, running fine with *Delphi 7*. Needs at least *Windows 7*.

Comment: Could you mention, which units were used in uses section.

Comment: @AliReza: The declarations (types, constants, and functions) needed here aren't available in a new RAD Studio setup, so AmigoJack probably translated them himself or found some translation somewhere.

Comment: @AliReza: I think all you need is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26406082/282848. I started translating it but it is very late now.

Comment: @AliReza none. I guess you want the definitions, so I added them to my code.

Comment: Now I can correctly read the monitor model, but the problem is that I can only identify one. I have tried to run it on several test PCs and I always get the same behavior.

Comment: I noticed that inside the `for i loop:= 0 to Integer (iMode) - 1 do` only one monitor enters the case with `aMode[i].infoType = DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO_TYPE_TARGET`

Answer (score 1):

First you must know some monitor doesn't have registered name in windows but if they have a name and you can read it with a program like **MultiMonitorTool**, So you can read it with **Delphi** too.

You can read **EDID** key value from the registry.
Value of **EDID** key create when monitor installed and can be overwritten by monitor driver.

This program read EDID for the active monitors.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Win.Registry, Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.MultiMon,
   Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, System.StrUtils,
   System.Character;

function GetMonitorName(index : Integer) : String;
const
  Key = '\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\';
type
  IBMString = type Ansistring(1253);
var
  Handle: HMONITOR;
  i, j, k : Integer;
  Registry: TRegistry;
  MonitorName : IBMString;
  DispDev : TDisplayDevice;
  subKeysNames : TStringList;
  MonitorInfo : TMonitorInfoEx;
  DeviceIDSplit : TArray<String>;
  EDID : array [0 .. 127] of Byte;
  DeviceName, DeviceString, DeviceID, DeviceKey, Driver : string;
begin
  Result := '';

  Handle := Screen.Monitors[index].Handle;
  MonitorInfo.cbSize := sizeof(MonitorInfo);
  if GetMonitorInfo(Handle, @MonitorInfo) then
  begin
    DispDev.cb := sizeof(DispDev);
    EnumDisplayDevices(@MonitorInfo.szDevice, 0, DispDev, 0);
    DeviceName   := StrPas(DispDev.DeviceName);     //'\\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0'    //This Line Can Be Removed
    DeviceString := StrPas(DispDev.DeviceString);   //'Generic PnP Monitor'      //This Line Can Be Removed
    DeviceID     := StrPas(DispDev.DeviceID);
    DeviceKey    := StrPas(DispDev.DeviceKey);                                   //This Line Can Be Removed

    DeviceIDSplit := DeviceID.Split(['\']);
    if Length(DeviceIDSplit) < 3 then Exit;
    Driver := '';
    for i := 2 to High(DeviceIDSplit) do
      Driver := Driver + '\' + DeviceIDSplit[i];
    System.Delete(Driver, 1, 1);

    subKeysNames := TStringList.Create;
    Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    try
      try
        Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key);
        Registry.GetKeyNames(subKeysNames);
      finally
        Registry.CloseKey;
      end;
      if subKeysNames.IndexOf(DeviceIDSplit[1]) < 0 then Exit;
      try
        Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + DeviceIDSplit[1]);
        Registry.GetKeyNames(subKeysNames);
      finally
        Registry.CloseKey;
      end;

      for i := 0 to subKeysNames.Count - 1 do
      begin
        try
          if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + DeviceIDSplit[1] + '\' + subKeysNames[i]) then
          begin
            if Registry.ReadString('Driver') <> Driver then Continue;
            Registry.CloseKey;
            if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + DeviceIDSplit[1] + '\' + subKeysNames[i] + '\' + 'Device Parameters') then
            begin
              Registry.ReadBinaryData('EDID', EDID, 128);
              Registry.CloseKey;
            end;
            for j := 0 to 3 do
            begin
              if (EDID[54 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[55 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[56 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[57 + 18 * j] = $FC) and
                 (EDID[58 + 18 * j] = 0) then
              begin
                k := 0;
                while (EDID[59 + 18 * j + k] <> $A) and (k < 13) do
                  Inc(k);
                SetString(MonitorName, PAnsiChar(@EDID[59 + 18 * j]), k);
                Result := MonitorName;
                Break;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        finally
          Registry.CloseKey;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Registry.Free;
      subKeysNames.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  i : Integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.MonitorCount-1 do
  begin
    Writeln(GetMonitorName(i));
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

and this program read all of monitor names, some of them may don't have a name.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Win.Registry, Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.MultiMon,
   Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, System.StrUtils,
   System.Character;

function GetAllMonitorName : TStrings;
const
  Key = '\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\';
type
  IBMString = type Ansistring(1253);
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  H, i, j, k : Integer;
  MonitorName : IBMString;
  EDID : array [0 .. 127] of Byte;
  subKeysNames, subKeys : TStringList;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;

  subKeys := TStringList.Create;
  subKeysNames := TStringList.Create;
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  try
    try
      Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key);
      Registry.GetKeyNames(subKeysNames);
    finally
      Registry.CloseKey;
    end;

    for h := 0 to subKeysNames.Count - 1 do
    begin
      try
        Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + subKeysNames[h]);
        Registry.GetKeyNames(subKeys);
      finally
        Registry.CloseKey;
      end;

      for i := 0 to subKeys.Count - 1 do
      begin
        try
          if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + subKeysNames[h] + '\' + subKeys[i]) then
          begin
            if registry.OpenKeyReadOnly(Key + subKeysNames[h] + '\' + subKeys[i] + '\' + 'Device Parameters') then
            begin
              Registry.ReadBinaryData('EDID', EDID, 128);
              Registry.CloseKey;
            end;
            MonitorName := '';
            for j := 0 to 3 do
            begin
              if (EDID[54 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[55 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[56 + 18 * j] = 0) and
                 (EDID[57 + 18 * j] = $FC) and
                 (EDID[58 + 18 * j] = 0) then
              begin
                k := 0;
                while (EDID[59 + 18 * j + k] <> $A) and (k < 13) do
                  Inc(k);
                SetString(MonitorName, PAnsiChar(@EDID[59 + 18 * j]), k);
                Break;
              end;
            end;
            Result.Add(MonitorName);
          end;
        finally
          Registry.CloseKey;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    subKeys.Free;
    Registry.Free;
    subKeysNames.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  i : Integer;

begin
  Writeln(GetAllMonitorName.Text);
  Readln;
end.
```

And if you want write a program like **MultiMonitorTool**, you can read more information from **EDID**, for more information read [Extended Display Identification Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)

Comment: This only lists monitors which were ever connected in the past, not now - it's a history, not a snapshot. And for my ID `MONITOR\MS_0005\...` no key exists at `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\` either, only 5 others from the past.

Comment: There is another path check 'SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\DISPLAY'

Comment: Not in your code. And it wouldn't help either, see [How does CurrentControlSet differ from ControlSet001 and ControlSet002?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291528/4299358)